# Can I use an expired UK sponsor letter for a visa application?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, applications

My uncle who lives in the UK sent me a visa sponsor letter for the UK, but I was too lazy to apply and now I realize that I am too late as 90 days have already passed. Is there any possibility that I can still use this letter to apply for a UK visit visa?

Comment: You should be able to use it if the dates for the proposed visit haven’t passed. If they have you’ll need to get a new invitation letter.